# Livedata is not updating after click login button more than one time

Tags: android, android-livedata

Retrofit response not updated in the Livedata object after clicking log in button more than one time

I have created a repository to update live data but it is not working

First, I entered the wrong credentials and then I have entered Right one.
Still, I am getting the same response

**LoginViewModel.kt**

```
fun getNumber(phone: String, password: String): MutableLiveData<String> {
        Log.i(TAG, "Get number")
        if (responseData == null) {
            responseData = MutableLiveData<String>()    
            this.phone = phone
            this.password = password
            createNumber()
        }
        return responseData as MutableLiveData<String>
    }


fun createNumber() {

    var apiServices = APIClient.client.create(APIInterface::class.java)
    val call = apiServices.getdata(phone, password)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
            responseData?.value = t.message

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {

            responseData?.value = response.body()?.string()
        }
    })
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
    btn_login!!.setOnClickListener {

        if (edit_userName!!.editableText.toString() != ""
            && edit_passWord!!.editableText.toString() != "") {
            layout_progress!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE;

                model?.getNumber(edit_userName!!.editableText.trim().toString(), edit_passWord!!.editableText.trim().toString())
                    ?.observe(this, Observer {

                        var jsonobject: JSONObject = JSONObject(it)

                        var message: String = jsonobject.getString("message")

                        if (message.equals("Login Success")) {
                            startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                            finish()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "You are not registered User....Please Contact Admin",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            layout_progress?.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    })
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Username and Password should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting this response from retrofit? **Kindly help me to get a proper response..if any GitHub link for the solution kindly share.**

Comment: Yes @RichardStokes

Comment: Two problems: (1) Since `responseData` is null only when the `getNumber()` is called for the first time, `createNumber()` will be called only once even if you call `getNumber()` multiple times. (2) Every time `btn_login` is clicked, you are attaching a new observer. If you click that button more than once there will be duplicated observers.

Comment: To summarize, you are getting the same response because you are actually not making any new response, but you are only attaching a new observer to the existing `LiveData` which contains the previous result.

Comment: Why so many ?s and !!s?

Answer (score 0):

can you change your code like this

```
fun getNumber(): MutableLiveData<String> {

        if (responseData == null) {
            responseData = MutableLiveData<String>()    
        }
        return responseData as MutableLiveData<String>
    }


fun createNumber(phone: String, password: String) {

    var apiServices = APIClient.client.create(APIInterface::class.java)
    val call = apiServices.getdata(phone, password)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
            responseData?.value = t.message

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {

            responseData?.value = response.body()?.string()
        }
    })
}

 model?.getNumber()
                    ?.observe(this, Observer {

                        var jsonobject: JSONObject = JSONObject(it)

                        var message: String = jsonobject.getString("message")

                        if (message.equals("Login Success")) {
                            startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                            finish()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "You are not registered User....Please Contact Admin",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            layout_progress?.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    })

 btn_login!!.setOnClickListener {

          model?.currentNumber(edit_userName!!.editableText.trim().toString(), edit_passWord!!.editableText.trim().toString())

    }
```